# Restfull service, not updating some attributes of an object

Tags: java, mysql, rest, jpa, merge

I have the object Usuario, I want to update it into the database, but it only save the changes in some attributtes.

```
@Entity
public class Usuario {

@Id
String nombre_Usuario;
String contrasena;
String estado;


@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
Posicion miPosicion;

}

@Entity
public class Posicion {

@Id
int id;
float latitud;
float longitud;
float altura;


public Posicion() {

    id = (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);
    latitud = longitud = altura = 0;
}

public Posicion(float alatitud, float alongitud, float aaltura) {
    id = (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);
    latitud = alatitud;
    longitud = alongitud;
    altura = aaltura;
}
```

I'm working with a restfull service and when I want to change the object I do:

```
Usuario u = new Usuario();
u = todoService.obtenerUsuarioBusqueda("user_name"); //Here I get the object I want to change

u.setEstado("New Estado");

u.setmiPosicion(new Posicion(10,10,10));

todoService.saveUsuario(u);



public String saveUsuario(Usuario u){

    try{
        entityManager.merge(u);
    }catch(Exception e){
        return "false"+e.getMessage();
    }
    return "true";

}
```

I make this for update the object in the database. And when I make a find(u), the estado is "New Estado", but when I try to get the attribute miPosicion it is null.

Just after making u.setmiPosicion(), if I make u.getmiPosicion() it is correct, the Posicion I have set. But when I make it from the object from find(u) it is null.

Comment: follow the .merge with a .flush

Comment: It's the same, one attribute is updated, but the other not

Comment: why `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn`? try removing that and do it

Comment: that was the problem! It works now, thank you so much!